# How to warn user that VSIX takes time to load?

Tags: visual-studio, user-experience, vsix

I want to warn user our extension is taking time and it is best to wait for it to be loaded

The problem is that sending messages to any output window is only done when my vsix starts:

```cs
m_serviceProvidor = serviceProvidor;
m_dte = (DTE2)serviceProvidor.GetService(typeof(DTE));
OutputWindowPanes panes = m_dte?.ToolWindows?.OutputWindow?.OutputWindowPanes;
m_outputWindow = panes.Add("MyVSIX");
m_SolutionOutputWindow = panes.Item("Solution");
m_SolutionOutputWindow.OutputString("Please wait for VSIX to be fully loaded ...");
```

This message arrives too late.

How can I add a message in the output window, at the very start of Visual studio?

Comment: You could add another piece of your installer which adds a little "monitor" package which is monitoring the status of your main one and logs to output.